# having problems making and installing gcc

Tags: gcc, makefile, rhel, rhel7, gcc7

I am having trouble installing gcc.  Given the information below, what am I doing wrong?

From `$HOME/gcc` on a Linux computer that I do not have root access to, I run the following:

```
$ wget http://mirrors.concertpass.com/gcc/releases/gcc-7.3.0/gcc-7.3.0.tar.gz
$ tar xvf gcc-7.3.0.tar.gz
$ cd gcc-7.3.0
$ ./contrib/download_prerequisites

gmp-6.1.0.tar.bz2: OK
mpfr-3.1.4.tar.bz2: OK
mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz: OK
isl-0.16.1.tar.bz2: OK
All prerequisites downloaded successfully.

$ cd ..
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ ../gcc-7.3.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc/test --disable-multilib
```

only a few lines of output are shown here:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
...
# lots of checking for, where, whether ...
...
/home/clay.stevens/package/gcc/gcc-7.3.0/missing: line 81: makeinfo: command not found
...
# lots of checking for, where, whether ...
...
config.status: creating Makefile
```

Attempt to make:

```
$ make -j8
```

`-j8` flag to use 8 cpus
only a few lines of output are shown here:

```
...
configure: WARNING:
*** Makeinfo is missing. Info documentation will not be built.
...
configure: WARNING: the "none" host is obsolete, use --disable-assembly
...
configure: summary of build options:

  Version:           GNU MP 6.1.0
  Host type:         none-pc-linux-gnu
  ABI:               standard
  Install prefix:    /home/user.name/gcc/test
  Compiler:          gcc -std=gnu99
  Static libraries:  yes
  Shared libraries:  no
...
...
config.status: executing default commands
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user.name/gcc/test'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user.name/gcc/test'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Attempt to install:

```
$ make install
```

errors:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user.name/gcc/test'
/bin/sh ../gcc-7.3.0/mkinstalldirs /home/user.name/gcc/test /home/user.name/gcc/test
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user.name/gcc/test/fixincludes'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user.name/gcc/test/fixincludes'
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user.name/gcc/test'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

#### System info:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-039.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016

$ cat /etc/*release  
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"  
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"  
ID="rhel"  
ID_LIKE="fedora"  

$ lsb_release -a  
LSB Version: :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch  
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
```

Answer (score 0):

The `makeinfo` program (which creates GNU info files) is not a prerequisite like the items downloaded with `download_prerequisites`.

To install `makeinfo`, run

```
yum install texinfo
```

Comment: Thanks, but `You need to be root to perform this command.`  Also, is that the reason it is not making?

Comment: downloaded `texinfo-6.5.tar.gz`  ran `./configure --prefix=$HOME` then `make`  Lots of apparently successful output, then errors:  `Can't locate Data/Dumper.pm in @INC` (...) `at ../tp/Texinfo/Common.pm line 2427.` ... `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../tp/Texinfo/Common.pm line 2427.`  ... `Compilation failed` ...  `--compilation aborted at ../tp/texi2any line 110.`  ... `*** [texinfo.info] Error 2` ...  `*** [info-stnd.info] Error 2` ... *** `[all-recursive] Error 1` ...  `*** [all-recursive] Error 1` ...  `*** [all] Error 2`

Comment: @Clay No, you don't have to be root to compile gcc. But to install any program into system directories (`/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`) you need to be root.

Comment: @Clay Looks like your build uses a perl program requiring Data::Dumper. Install that as well as root; use `yum install perl-Data-Dumper`. Keep installing until everything works. Welcome to the world of twisty little dependencies :-)

Comment: thanks,  but when I run `yum install texinfo` or `yum install perl-Data-Dumper` the system responds with `You need to be root to perform this command.`  So it looks like my only option is to `wget`, `./configure --prefix=$HOME/somedir` and then `make` each dependency .

Comment: @Clay Installing tools as non-root opens a different can of worms. I suggest you ask the admin of the system to install what you need.